C# Read from clipboard and save to variable
I try to get my clipboard (it will always be a 6 digit number, e. g. 123456 when the code is executed) content to be saved to a variable. However, the variable seems to be empty.
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        string code = Clipboard.GetText();
        //Following 4 lines with text are not releveant, they add the region the code is for and will save it in the program itself and post a chat message.
        string input = args["rawInput"].ToString();
        string lobbyCode = $"{input} {code}";
        
        CPH.SetTwitchUserVar(userName, "Phasmo code", lobbyCode, true);
        CPH.SendMessage("Code has been read from clipboard and is now stored in a variable! ✅ ", true);
        return true;
    }
}

Is what I tried. What am I doing wrong?

So there is another point in your code when the Cliboard is set? Did you check if that part is correct?

@Renat - The OP is using System.Windows.Forms. The question you referred to is WPF.

args is typically an array of strings so calling .ToString() is unnecessary.

I just ran string code = Clipboard.GetText(); and it works perfectly fine. You really need to help us replicate the issue otherwise we can't help. We need a [mcve].

We can't guess what's going on. Does the clipboard contain anything to begin with? Is it text or eg an image copied from a web browser? You may think you've stored text in the clipboard but this code doesn't show it

Are you trying to use the clipboard as some kind of cross-thread or cross-process communication mechanism? That's not a good idea and frankly, that's not how applications work since the 2000s. Applications used such data exchange mechanisms in the 1990s, when all applications were desktop applications, as all those techniques depend on the desktop and window messages. That doesn't work with any background process (eg services) nor does it allow transferring complex data above a few KBs

@Steve What do you mean with Clipboard set? This is the entirety of my code I posted here....

Your code doesn't store anything to the clipboard, so where do you expect the text to come from? What happens if you open Notepad and select Paste? Do you see any text?
